# Pass parameter to MDX/Tabular Object Model Cube using tableau parameter/filter

Tags: mdx, tableau-api, dax, ssas-tabular, mdx-query

I have below things:
 Tableau report (with Year and Month)
 The tableau report is pointing to Tabular Object Model Cube
 Tabular Object Model contains date dimension, region dimension and fact sales

Trying to achieve below:
 When the user selects a year and a month from the report, the report should give me sales for previous 3 quarters with reference to the month selected

If your solution proposes to use a MDX query, then it would be great if you can point to some link, to illustrate how this can be done.

I have tried below:
Dragged Year and Quarter in rows(in tableau) and dragged the calculated field in column. This gives me sales across all quarters for all years but I want to limit this information to previous 3 quarters based on the Year and month selected by the user.

Comment: can you add what you have already tried?

Comment: IN a Microsoft system you can add VBA to MDX in order to build up member names as strings. It is a bit clunky, but careful use can create the right dates you need. I cannot offer a full answer as I do not know how Tableau is passing the chosen year/month to the MDX query.